# Double Integrals & Expected Value Monte Carlo Method in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, numerical-methods, montecarlo

The following algorithm works well for mono-dimensional cases, but I would like to modify it to handle double integrals. How can I do this?

```
class doubleIntMonteCarlo
{
    private static double f(double x)
    {
        return 1 / Math.pow( x , 2 );
    }

    public static double doubleIntMonteCarlo(double a, double b, int n)
    {
        double xSum = 0D, ySum = 0D, sum = 0D;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xSum = a + Math.random() * Math.abs( b - a );
            sum += f(xSum);
        }
        return Math.abs( b - a ) * sum / n;
    }
}

public class MonteCarloIntegration 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(doubleIntMonteCarlo.doubleIntMonteCarlo(10, 250, 100000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static double doubleIntMonteCarlo(double a, double b, double c, double d, int n)
{
     double sum = 0D, xSum = 0D, ySum = 0D;

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
           xSum = a + Math.random() * Math.abs(b - a);
           ySum = c + Math.random() * Math.abs(d - c);
           sum += f(xSum, ySum);
     }
     return Math.abs(b - a) * Math.abs(d - c) * sum / n;
}
```

Comment: I can't up-vote, but thank you! I've edited your answer because of some errors in the sintax! and lol I was so close!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry for errors, I tested it in C# :).